# Matlab - How to run loops (functions) in parallel?

Tags: matlab

I'm new to Matlab; looking to run two loops in parallel. I want one loop to read in an audio signal and output it to the speakers after some transform, and another loop to simply output the signal to a plot all in realtime. My solution is to have loop 1 output the signal to a vector which would then get read by the loop and stuck in the plot in the GUI. I can't for the life of me wrap my head around any form of parallel processing in Matlab, so any help is appreciated. Here's my loops (functions):

```
function results = plot_to_gui(app)
        while app.Button.Value == 1 || length(app.signals) > 0
            try 
                plot(app.UIAxes, app.signals(1));
                app.signals(1) = [];
                output = "test";
            catch ME
                disp("caught!");
            end
            drawnow
            disp("2");
        end
        results = 1;
    end
    
    function results = loop_voice(app)
        frameLength = 256;
            
        fs = 16000;
        t = -1:1/fs:1;

        deviceReader = audioDeviceReader;
        disp("here!!");
        setup(deviceReader);
        deviceWriter = audioDeviceWriter('SampleRate',deviceReader.SampleRate);
    
        while app.Button.Value == 1
            Read Signal
            signal = deviceReader();
            deviceWriter(signal);
            app.signals = [app.signals, signal];
            disp("voice!");
            drawnow
            disp("1");
            
        end
        release(deviceReader)
        release(deviceWriter)
        results = 1;
    end
```

And here's where I'm attempting to use parfeval to run the loops.

```
while app.Button.Value == 1
            for n = 1 : 2
                if n == 1
                    parfeval(loop_voice(app));
                else 
                    parfeval(plot_to_gui(app));
                end
            end  
        end
```

Currently getting this error: Undefined function 'parfeval' for input arguments of type 'double'.
I'm very lost and I'd appreciate a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: “I can't for the life of me wrap my head around any form of parallel processing in Matlab” That’s about right. MATLAB is sequential. If you have the Parallel Toolbox, there is a way you can do multi-threaded computation, but it’s limited to *computation*. By default the Parallel Toolbox works with multiple processes, not multiple threads (i.e. multiple MATLAB sessions that talk to each other). I don’t think it is possible to do what you want to do. Why do you need the parallelism? Does it not work in a single thread?

Comment: I suppose I don't understand the concept of multi-threading and parallel processing very well at all. What I'm trying to do is read a signal from a device (microphone), spit it out to my speakers, and then visualize the signal in real time. Ideally, I'd be able to apply some transformation to the signal in real time, as well. When I try to do it all sequentially, the audio I hear from the speakers gets choppy (because of the call to plot to the GUI). I'm trying to avoid the choppiness.

Answer (score 3):

Base Matlab is single-threaded at the M-code level, and there is no way to do parallel or multithreaded execution. (Though many built-in Matlab functions are internally multithreaded in their implementations, so it can still make efficient use of multi-core CPUs.)

If you purchase the Matlab Parallel Computing Toolbox, you could use its [Asynchronous Parallel Programming facility](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/asynchronous-parallel-programming.html) to do parallel execution of M-code in a multi-processing style manner. Communication between the parallel processes happens through message passing, not shared memory. (`parfeval` is part of the Parallel Computing Toolbox; that's why you're getting an "undefined" error when you try to call it.)

But outside of the Matlab documentation, you won't find many resources on how to do this, because as far as I can tell very few people do it, and the Async Parallel Programming stuff is quite new. Doing this kind of stuff in Matlab is kind of unnatural. Yea, some may even call it an abomination.

Could you maybe port this to, say, Python or Java?

If you do proceed to do this in Matlab, try to conceptualize your program as a single-threaded "main" program that runs in the main Matlab instance as an event loop of sorts, and treats your other "worker" processes as semi-independent computing and I/O facilities with which you communicate via asynchronous message passing, as though they were services of some sort, rather than other threads inside the same program.

Comment: I understand that you can set up the Parallel Toolbox to do multi-threaded rather than multiple processes. This seems quite new, I’ve never tried it. With multiple threads you have a shared memory parallelism, but only the main thread is allowed to do I/O, meaning that other threads can only compute.

Comment: Yeah. You can do the `'threads'` worker pool option, and it's in-process so it saves some overhead on the interprocess communication, but (AFAICT) the programming model is still the same and the workers' memory spaces are all effectively isolated, so it still looks more like you're doing multiprocessing instead of multithreading programming. (That is, _you_ don't have access to the shared memory.) I haven't played around with it yet, but it looks like it's basically an IPC I/O optimization and not something that makes your code look any more like traditional multithreaded code.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Can you expand on the "only the main thread is allowed to do I/O" limitation? I'm not familiar with this.

Comment: Ah, interesting, and it makes sense. It is thus the same as the normal `parfor` but without having to send parts of the data to the workers. The I/O restrictions I new from here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/choose-between-thread-based-and-process-based-environments.html#mw_6bbf0761-74c0-404e-9db6-77b82c7c138c -- so maybe you can do `disp`, but there's no file I/O and no handle graphics.

Comment: `parfeval` was added to Parallel Computing Toolbox back in R2013b... not all that "new"!

Comment: You're right! It's just the `send` and `poll` for message passing that are newer.